# Qualitatively connecting classical Poisson brackets and quantum commutators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, commutator, poisson-brackets

I have read many answers on the correspondence between classical Poisson brackets and quantum commutators, but I was wondering if it was able to be spelled out in simple words.

In this answer ([What is the physical interpretation of the Poisson bracket](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/176164/)) they say 'you can consider the Poisson bracket {,} as expressing the rate of change of  as a consequence of a flow induced by ...When = and =, since the momenta are the generators of translations, the flow generated by  can be interpreted as translations, so that the canonical bracket {,}=1 implies a variation of ={,}='.

So would I be at all correct in saying the reason why this implies that the quantum commutation relation $[\hat x,\hat p]=i\hbar$ (and ultimately that position and momentum are not simultaneously measurable) is because QM uses operators and therefore the above Poisson bracket shows that $\hat x \hat p$ generates a translation 'flow' before measuring position whereas $\hat p \hat x$ generates a translation 'flow' after measuring position (and this is not the case where the Poisson bracket is zero)?

What exactly then is the distinction here between classical and quantum mechanics. If $p$ generates a flow in $x$ in both theories, but in QM this causes $p$ and $x$ to not commute, but in CM they can still commute?

Comment: Possible duplicate:  [What is the connection between Poisson brackets and commutators?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19770/2451)

Comment: You are getting faked out by the difference in formalism between the two theories. When you describe [QM in phase space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-space_formulation), classical phase space, by [translating QM operators to phase-space language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner–Weyl_transform), you see that QM "corrects" CM through corrections of order ℏ, observable functions multiply non-commutatively, and flows in phase space are modified. Can you sharpen your question?

Comment: Quantum flows are [compressible in phase space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/415073/whats-the-intuitive-reason-that-phase-space-flow-is-incompressible-in-classical), much unlike classical flows, so the probability fluid diffuses in QM.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/321677/the-quantum-analogue-of-liouvilles-theorem).